# Setting up bracketing on a D7000

Tags: bracketing

I went though the steps, but in csm/bracketing/flash e2 through e6 are not highlighted. When right click on e5-Autobracketing, a balloon pops up "option not available on this setting" what did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You're in the wrong mode.  Either Auto or one of the 'Scene' modes which take over many of the camera functions.

Set your camera to either P (Program), S (Shutter Priority) or A (Aperture Priority) mode and bracketing will become available along with a load of other options.

The manual will tell you in more detail which modes all of your cameras features do (and don't) work in.

Answer (score -1):

Those options probably are only enabled if you are in Aperture or Shutter priority, or full Manual exposure modes.  If you are in full Auto or Program mode, or a scene mode, many options are not available, as those modes let the camera decide for you.  You may need also to check the metering mode.  Spot metering for example may limit your choices as well.

Comment: P is fine for bracketing.  You treat it just the same as A/S modes.